# Cannot close a Delphi form without causing a Beep

Tags: delphi

I have a PopUpform containing 1 edit box. I call ShowModal from the main form and using Enter and Escape in the PopUpform.keyDown event to close the PopUp and set the appropriate modal result when it returns to the main form.

Opening the form and closing it when the edit box has focus causes a beep.  If the editbox doesn't have focus the form closes silently.  What can I do to prevent the beep when the edit box has focus?

Comment: I think that this solves your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770207/how-to-avoid-the-ding-sound-when-escape-is-pressed-while-a-tedit-is-focused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a dialog box contains an **OK** and a **Cancel** button, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key "clicks" the **OK** button and the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key "clicks" the **Cancel** button.

To manage the dialog box, you set the **OK** button's `Default` property to `True` and the **Cancel** button's `Cancel` property to `True`. In addition, these buttons should also have the appropriate `ModalResult` values:

- btnOK

  Caption = "OK"
  Default = True
  ModalResult = mrOk
- btnCancel

  Caption = "Cancel"
  Cancel = True
  ModalResult = mrCancel

Then you show the dialog using `ShowModal`:

```pascal
frm := TFrogPropertiesFrm.Create(Self);
try
  if frm.ShowModal = mrOk then
    UpdateFrogProperties;
finally
  frm.Free;
end;
```

Notice that <kbd>Enter</kbd> automatically "clicks" the **OK** button and that <kbd>Escape</kbd> automatically "clicks" then **Cancel** button. Also notice that the defaultness of the **OK** button is indicated by a thick border.

If, instead, you have a dialog box with only a single button, this is typically captioned **Close** and should have both `Default` and `Cancel` set to `True`. Its modal result can be `mrClose`, for instance.

---

This being said, *if* your form really doesn't have any suitable buttons and you do

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    VK_RETURN:
      ModalResult := mrOk;
    VK_ESCAPE:
      ModalResult := mrCancel;
  end;
end;
```

you can silence the beep by doing

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = Chr(VK_RETURN) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Comment: As I said in my original post, the form only contains a single text Edit.  In fact it will be embedded in the main form code and created at run time. So I now cancel the beep as you suggested.Thank you for reminding me of that mechanism.

Comment: Ah, as a mathematician, I interpret "a PopUpform containing 1 edit box" as saying that the form contains at least one edit box, and possibly other things (while "a PopUpform containing nothing but a single edit box" is unambiguous). :) In any case, I suspect this post will be seen by many Google users that might actually have the buttons I talk about, so it would be rather irresponsible of me not to mention that approach, even if it isn't relevant in your particular case!